# Fatal Error: Call to undefined function _()

Tags: php, printing, cups

I'm trying to use [this php class](http://www.nongnu.org/phpprintipp/) on my CUPS Server.

Now when I try to call a function from this class, i get
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function _() in /usr/local/share/php/printipp/BasicIPP.php on line 344`

Line 344 Looks like this:

```
self::_putDebug(sprintf(_("Charset: %s") , $charset) , 2);
```

Inside the following function:

```
 public function setCharset($charset = 'us-ascii') 
{
 $charset = strtolower($charset);
 $this->charset = $charset;
 $this->meta->charset = chr(0x47) // charset type | value-tag
  . chr(0x00) . chr(0x12) // name-length
  . "attributes-charset" // attributes-charset | name
  . self::_giveMeStringLength($charset) // value-length
  . $charset; // value
 self::_putDebug(sprintf(_("Charset: %s") , $charset) , 2);
 $this->setup->charset = 1;
}
```

My PHP Version is 5.3.26. What is the _() function and how am i missing it?

EDIT**
It looks like _() is an alias for gettext().
After checking with package manager i have 0.17 Version Of Gettext installed.
How do i enable it in php?

Comment: (In short: It is an alias for the [`gettext()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php) function.)

Comment: @AmalMurali Okay, why isn't my php recognizing this?

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/gettext.installation.php

Comment: If you're on linux, check your package manager for `gettext`.  In Debian: `sudo apt-get gettext`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Looks like i have 0.17 Version of Gettext package installed.

Comment: @jszobody Which file do I add that installation line?

Answer (score 1):

This error message appears because the `gettext` extension has not been enabled in PHP.

You can check this with a `phpinfo()` where there should be a table for **gettext** which contains a row: `GetText Support - enabled`
If you can only find an entry in the **PHP Credits** table - it's not enabled.

It can be enabled by adding `extension=gettext` to *php.ini*.